# Updating field attributes by annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, java-annotations

I'm reviewing how reflection works or possible work. I have this `SomeClassBuilder` wherein it has an attribute `target : Target` with declared annotation `TargetAnnotation`.

Thing is, is it possible to override/update the values/properties of `Target` wherein upon invoke of `someMethod()` would return the parameters on the annotation?

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface TargetAnnotation {
    String first();
    String second();
    // other attributes
}

public class Target {
    String first;
    String second;
    // some other attributes unique only to `Target`
}

public interface TargetHelper {
    void setTarget(Target target);
}

public class SomeClassBuilder implements TargetHelper {

    @TargetAnnotation(first = "first", second = "second")
    private Target target;

    @Override public void setTarget(Target target) { this.target = target }

    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println(target.first); // should be `first`
        System.out.println(target.second); // should be `second`
    }

}
```

Or is it even possible to do it without `TargetHelper` interface?

Let's say I have this `TargetProcessor` called before `SomeClassBuilder` which sole purpose is to fill-in the `target : Target` annotated with `@TargetAnnotation` and assign the field/attributes from `@TargetAnnotaton` to `Target`.

```
public class TargetProcessor {
    public void parse() {
        // look into `@TargetAnnotation`
        // map `@TargetAnnotation` properties to `Target`
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood this right you got a field which got an annotation on it that defines the values for that field, right?

Comment: @CodeMatrix, yes. Please see updated content.

Comment: You can use `Processor` or create the instance by factory method. I can give an example later.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by implementing Annotation Processor for your annotation *@TargetAnnotation*

For further readings and examples:

1. http://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder
2. https://github.com/bozaro/example-annotation-processor/blob/master/example-modify/processor/src/main/java/ru/bozaro/processor/HelloProcessor.java
3. https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/

This article explains, how it should be done:

1. http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101

Comment: Maven is used for compilation here. Below example you can follow for without maven compilation too. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-annotation-processors.html

Comment: Check out the article i have mentioned as last link

Comment: Still not a solution for me since I can't invoke any classes of `AbstractProcessor`

Comment: You don't need to invoke any class, but you need to provide while compile like _-processor YourAnnotationProcessor class_

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
import static xdean.jex.util.lang.ExceptionUtil.uncheck;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import xdean.jex.util.reflect.ReflectUtil;

public class Q46765735 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    create(TargetDomain.class).printTarget();
  }

  public static <T> T create(Class<T> clz) {
    T target = uncheck(() -> clz.newInstance());
    Stream.of(ReflectUtil.getAllFields(clz, false)).forEach(f -> uncheck(() -> fill(target, f)));
    return target;
  }

  private static <T> void fill(T target, Field field) throws Exception {
    TargetAnnotation anno = field.getAnnotation(TargetAnnotation.class);
    if (anno == null) {
      return;
    }
    Class<?> type = field.getType();
    if (!Target.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
      return;
    }
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Target value = (Target) field.get(target);
    if (value == null) {
      value = (Target) type.newInstance();
    }
    value.setFirst(anno.first());
    value.setSecond(anno.second());
    field.set(target, value);
  }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@java.lang.annotation.Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@interface TargetAnnotation {
  String first();

  String second();
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Target {
  String first;
  String second;
}

class TargetDomain {

  @TargetAnnotation(first = "first", second = "second")
  private Target target = new Target("a", "b");

  public void printTarget() {
    System.out.println(target.first); // should be `first`
    System.out.println(target.second); // should be `second`
  }
}
```

Tips:

1. You can replace lombok by write constructor and getter/setter manually.
2. `ReflectUtil.getAllFields` get all fields of the class.
3. `uncheck` simply ignore exceptions, you can use try-catch.